# Lodash and map / filter / keys - better implementation?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have some data:

```
this.shoes = {
    {id: 1001, color: "red", cost: 100},
    {id: 1002, color: "red", cost: 50},
    {id: 1003, color: "blue", cost: 0}
}
```

I am using a combination of lodash and native implementation and curious if there is a more succinct way just using lodash.

what I have:

```
var shoes = this.shoes;
var avail = _.keys(shoes).filter(function(s){
               return shoes[s].cost > 0;
            }).map(function(){
                // return some data
            });
```

the reason I put "this.shoes" into a variable is because I need the "this" to be intact to the surrounding object. If I put the "this.shoes" in _.keys(), it doesnt work. If there is a way to "bind" my content to appply to all of the lodash methods that could work too.

my lodash expertise is lacking, so curious if I can shorten this up at all.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you even need `this.shoes` in a variable? Do you have a function? Can you show the surrounding code as well? Is `shoes` an array? It doesn't look like a valid array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.shoe` should be an array like

```
 this.shoes = [
    {id: 1001, color: "red", cost: 100},
    {id: 1002, color: "red", cost: 50},
    {id: 1003, color: "blue", cost: 0}
];
```

Then you can do:

```
var avail = _.filter(this.shoes, function(s){
               return s.cost > 0;
            }).map(function(){
                // return some data
            });
```

And certainly you don't need put "this.shoes" into a variable.

Comment: this.shoes can't be an array, I need the obj as a lookup. I can't do that as an array.. i could, but I'd have to loop thru the array, find the corresponding ID --- update it, reinsert it etc..